# Custom Flex 3 Container

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, mxml, custom-component

I'd like to create a custom Container in Flex 3.
I want this container to have an inner container which is either a TabNavigator or a VBox, depending on some flag the user sets. This flag won't change once the page is rendered, so I don't need to "dynamically" move from one component to another.

So far, I have this code:

```
public class AccNavigator extends Container {
public var container:Container;

public function AccNavigator() {
    if (GlobalSettings.Vertical) { // This is the said variable
        container = new VBox();
    }
    else {
        container = new TabNavigator();
    }
    container.percentHeight = 100;
    container.percentWidth = 100;
}

override protected function createChildren():void {
    super.createChildren();
    this.addChild(container);
}

override public function addChild(c:DisplayObject):DisplayObject {
    if (c == container) {
        // MessageAlert is the same as an Alert but with custom code
        MessageAlert.show("addChild: Adding Container");
        super.addChild(c);
    } else {
        MessageAlert.show("addChild: " + c.toString());
        container.addChild(c);
    }
    return c;
}

override protected function initializationComplete():void {
    // used for bebugging purposes
    MessageAlert.show("container is visible: " + container.visible.toString());
    MessageAlert.show("this is visible: " + visible.toString());
    MessageAlert.show("container children: " + container.numChildren);
    MessageAlert.show("this children: "+ this.numChildren);
}
}
```

I am using this custom container in mxml like this:

```
<AccNavigator>
   <HBox>
      <more things...>
   </HBox>
   <HBox>
      <more things...>
   </HBox>
</AccNavigator>
```

But when I run the application, none of the components are visible.
When the initializationComplete code is executed I see the following:

- container is visible: true
- this is visible: true
- container children: 2
- this children: 1

I have spent some time reading this http://www.developmentarc.com/site/sites/default/files/understanding_the_flex_3_lifecycle_v1.0.pdf
to understand the component lifecycle but still I can't make sense of what is missing in my code.

Can someone please help me and tell me what am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I shouldn't have extended Container.
So, the class declaration looks like:

```
public class AccNavigator extends VBox {
....
}
```

Everything else is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Extend from the Container type you want your container to be based on. e.g. extend from HBox if you want to have something based on HBox or VBox if you want to implement something based on VBox. You technically, can extend Container but since Container is too close to the 'root' of the hierarchy you would have to 'reinvent the wheel' in some way.